# First name and last name to Twitter handle

Tags: twitter

I have a list of people (first and last name) who I want to follow, but I don't want to Google or search them via Twitter separately. What is the best way to get the Twitter handles? Some GitHub repos or tutorials are also fine.

Comment: When Twitter Search can give you direct result, why don't you want to? Use Twitter Search API, if you are using Java, go for twitter4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter offers a "[User Search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search)" API request.

If you want to search for a user named "Ada Lovelace" you will need to send an OAuth'd request to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Ada%20Lovelace
```

You will get back a list of results.  There may be many people who share the same first and last name.

As for *how* to do it, that rather depends on the programming language you want to use.

If you just want a clickable link, use https://twitter.com/search?q=Terence%20Eden

Answer (score 1):

So firstly this question is off-topic but I will try write an answer for you. You could use the twitter api for this but that might be a little overkill if you just want to do this for you.

**I made you an API**

I made an API just for you using KimonoLabs. You can use this and just make a script that loops through your list and requests this api every time, then return a list of the results. Here is the API endpoint:
https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/duwxgie4?apikey=D6UKiTtKU93kv0YJj8i3kFBAbsIjdSTC&q=PERSON%20NAME

The &q= is the paramater for the person's name. To seperate the first and last name use %20, like so: Robert%20Keus

The documentation for this api is here:
https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/duwxgie4

Let me know if you need any help,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Latest answer @ 2016

**First Solution**: I wrote following node.js script. You need `access_token` and `id` of pulicly published google doc spreadsheet. For testing purpose I have provided sample spreadsheet's link and its `id` in following code.

```
var Twit = require('twit'),
    async = require('async');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'xxxxxxxx',
    consumer_secret:      'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token:         'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_secret:  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    timeout_ms:           60*1000  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
});

//https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n7DxgJTTHZ9w3xwiHokUhXMLkBwpP5c9ZLFmsYFDCic/edit?usp=sharing

var GoogleSpreadsheet = require("google-spreadsheet"),
    _ = require('underscore');

var sheetId = req.params.sheet || "1n7DxgJTTHZ9w3xwiHokUhXMLkBwpP5c9ZLFmsYFDCic",
    sheet = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);

async.waterfall([
    function (cb) {
        sheet.getRows(1, {}, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); return;};
            var names = [];
            _.each(rows, function (row) {
                names.push(row.first + " " + row.last);
            });
            cb(null, names);
        });
    },
    function (names, callback1) {

        async.map(names, function(name, cb){
            T.get('users/search', { q: name, page: 1 }, function (err, data, response) {
                if(data.length)
                    cb(null, {screen_name: data[0].screen_name, name:data[0].name});
                else
                    cb(null, {screen_name: "no_data_retrieved", name: name});
            });
        }, function (err, results) {
            callback1(null, results);
        });

    },
    function (users, callback) {
        console.log(users); //**YOU GET ALL DESIRED DATA HERE**
    }
], function (err, result) {
    //handle in memory data
});
```

**Second Solution**: Clone node-cheat [twitter-screen-names](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/random/small_tasks/twitter-screen-names), run `npm install` and shoot `node server`, Now get all twitter `usernames` as `json` in browser.

Happy Helping!